# How are KeyValuePairs compared for equality?

Tags: c#, equality, keyvaluepair

I have two arrays of `KeyValuePair<string, object>`. I am comparing the two arrays, but noticed that when the value of the `KeyValuePair` is a value type cast to an object, like `object{int}`, two pairs with identical keys and value values are not considered equal. However, when a reference type is cast to a value, like `object{string}`, two pairs with identical key and value values are considered equal.

I discovered this problem when I was using the `.Except()` method on the two arrays, and noticed although they were identical only the pairs with string values were removed by the set difference. From what I've seen doing research on the equality comparer for `KeyValuePair`, equality is by value, and not by reference. Curiously, the reference for the pairs with string values should be different anyways.

```
// array1 and array2 contain the same keys with identical values here

var array1 = GetOldItems(); // This returns a KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
var array2 = GetNewItems(); // This returns a KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
var diff = array1.Except(array2); // The difference is all pairs with non-string value
```

`diff` ends up being all pairs in `array1` with a non-string value, even though all pairs in `array1` had identical keys and values to the pairs in `array2`.

EDIT: Here is the value of `array1` and `array2` as reported in the debugger:

```
{System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>[5]}
[0]: {[Prop1, 1]}
[1]: {[Prop2, A]}
[2]: {[Prop2, B]}
[3]: {[Prop3, 3]}
[4]: {[Prop1, 2]}
```

`Prop2` has keys where type of value is `object{string}` and the other pairs have values with type of `object{int}`.

All pairs for `Prop1` and `Prop3` remain in the set difference, while all pairs with `Prop2` have been removed.

Comment: An example of arrays with data that are failing would be helpful.

Comment: @Magnus just added failing data

Comment: A debugger view doesn't really tell us anything more. What is `A` here? What is `1` here? Also, it's really the contents that were started with that matter.

Comment: I tested it with two equal arrays containig `new KeyValuePair<string, object>[] {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Prop1", 1),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Prop2", "A"),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Prop2", "B"),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Prop3", 3),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Prop1", 2),
            };` and it works as excpected, I got empty result.

Comment: KeyValuePair does not override the Equals() method.  When you box it by casting to (object) then you get Object.Equals().  Which is never true for two boxed values since it compares for object identity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does KeyValuePair not override Equals() and GetHashCode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250596/why-does-keyvaluepair-not-override-equals-and-gethashcode)

Answer (score 1):

`KeyValuePair` uses the default approach to struct equality. If two `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` have `Key` properties that compare as equal for their type's default equality and `Value` properties that compare as equal for their type's default equality, then they are equal. Otherwise they are not.

I do not find what you report. E.g.:

```
new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("a", 2) }.Except(
  new[] { (new KeyValuePair<string, object>("a", 2))})
```

returns an empty sequence, because the contents of the two arrays are identical.

I would wonder if perhaps you have pairs where the values are some reference type that does not override `Equals()` and so are only considered equal if they are the same object. In other words, that `kvp1.Value.Equals(kvp2.Value)` would return false.